# Video Streaming in Android: dealing with format and headers

Tags: java, android, video, format, live-streaming

I'm currently trying to stream live video from an Android device. Unfortunately, I am unable to read the stream I got through the network.

I figured out that the problem is due to the format used for recording video (ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, 3GPP).

Here is how I initialize the recorder:

```
    // Sources
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

    // HD
    CamcorderProfile highProfile = CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    recorder.setProfile(highProfile);
    recorder.setOutputFile(PATH);
```

If the video is currently filmed (still writing on the FS), here is what I get when I read the start of the file (I got that file with `$ adb pull /sdcard/video`) :

```
MacBook-Romain:result rbochet$ hexdump video-current.mp4 | head -2
0000000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000010 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 6d 64 61 74
```

When the recording ends, the header looks like this:

```
MacBook-Romain:result rbochet$ hexdump video.mp4 | head -2
0000000 00 00 00 18 66 74 79 70 33 67 70 34 00 00 03 00
0000010 33 67 70 34 33 67 70 36 00 07 56 83 6d 64 61 74
```

The fact is that this method is not the best for live streaming, as we just do not know how long and big the file will be…

**Question:** How can I do to actual streaming?
One of the solution I see is sending small chunks, but I think this solution actually sucks... Something better should exist, as program such as SipDroid are able to stream.
If you are able to understand their code, can you explain it? I had a look at [the code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=fr#fCdYvDFICtw/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/ui/VideoCamera.java&q=video%20package%3ahttp://sipdroid%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc), but it was not that clear for me.

The code will be released as open source, so your help will be enjoyable by everyone who looks for a way to solve this tricky situation (I know there are lots of similar threads on SO).

Here is the code of the basic camera app: https://github.com/rbochet/Simple-Camera-App

Thanks for your help.

Comment: spartygw's comment: "Agreed that this stinks. The header for this format contains information that you wouldn't know until the complete file was recorded, so you can't predict what the header should be and thus support streaming.
I've tried capturing 1 second chunks which also stinks. I've currently resorted to doing ~15 frame grabs per second and compressing and sending which is totally ugly and brute force. If you have a nice streaming solution from an android phone I am all ears.
"